# Exclude htaccess for admin folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

1. How to disable `.htaccess` for some folders?
2. Example I want exclude htaccess for my `admin` folder
3. Let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this rule to stop the rewriting process for that specific URL path prefix:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin($|/) - [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like that in your `httpd.conf`

```
<Location /admin>
 AllowOverride None
</Location>
```

see the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride)