# exclude sub directory from htaccess rules in root folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, trailing-slash

I am using below htaccess rules on my website's root folder to remove the files extensions and add trailing slash at the end. However, I'd like to exclude a sub-directory /sub-dir/ from the root folder htaccess rules. I tried to add another htaccess to the /sub-dir/ folder and put `RewriteOptions inherit` or `RewriteEngine Off` in the file but none of them works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect from non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.mywebsite.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

# Remove trailing slash:
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L]

# Now test without the trailing slash:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13842523/2696690

Comment: @Winter Yes. I tried that. I think it didn't work because the rules on my htaccess file is different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either try adding an htaccess file in your subdirectory that has *only* this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Without any inherit options. Inherit means you want the rules in the parent htaccess to also be applied along with any rules in the subdirectory's htaccess file. With this, you're making sure the rewrite engine is on and making a "do nothing" pass-through rule.

Otherwise, you can add the passthrough at the top of the root's htaccess file (right below `RewriteBase`):

```
RewriteRule ^sub-dir/ - [L]
```

Comment: I tried {RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^ - [L]} and it works like a charm. Thanks heaps

Comment: Thanks, nice one :)

Comment: The first one did not work but the second one did.