# htaccess rewrite issue excluding folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `Wordpress` site that has a rewrite rule. I also have a non-wordpress folder, but I can't access it because of this rule. So I read that i should enter `RewriteEngine Off` in the `htaccess` of the non-wordpress folder, unfortunately I still get an Error 404 on that page (it works fine if I remove the `Wordpress` rewrite).

Here is the htaccess in the root:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Matt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded-folder/.*$` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837538/exclude-folder-from-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Add this right under `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/ - [L]
```

where `folder` is the folder you want to exclude.