# exclude folder in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

My htaccess was working fine and suddenly it has stopped, I want to exclude folder `myFolder` from cakephp, I tried to put `myFolder` in root and app/webroot folder but doesn't seems to work, it redirect to cakephp

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^myFolder - [L]
    RewriteBase  /app/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Is `myFolder` inside `app/` folder now?

Comment: Might this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837538/exclude-folder-from-htaccess