# Handling query params with htaccess rewrites and simple php switch case?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am new to php stuff, so the question might be a bit stupid:

index.php

```
<?php

include "rest/db.php" ;
$db = OpenCon();

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($request) {
    case '/' :
        require __DIR__ . '/home.php';
        break;
    case '/supply' :
        require __DIR__ . '/supply.php';
        break;
    case '/about' :
        require __DIR__ . '/about.php';
        break;
    case '/careers' :
        require __DIR__ . '/careers.php';
        break;

    ......//some more stuff

    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        require __DIR__ . '/404-page.php';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

1 question:
I need to handle request to `supply.php?page=5(or supply.php?page=5&offset=5)`. How do I need to change `index.php` and `htaccess` for that?

2 question:
I have admin template written in angular and hosted on the same hosting as this website(which is in php). Angular admin project is in `/adminv1` folder. The problem with it is that, when I do refresh the page, it goes to `404` page and loses the styles. I guess this is happening because of the request handling in `index.php`. What would be the simplest way to solve it?

[admin panel working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYqC0.png)

[admin panel after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2fUe.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Easiest way would be, if you do not evaluate `REQUEST_URI`, but pass the originally requested path as an extra parameter. `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?script=$1 [QSA,L]`. `$_GET['script']` should now contain `supply.php` with your given example URL.

Comment: 2. Exclude everything below the `/adminv1` path from your rewriting, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13842523/1427878

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the documentation to learn about the different content you can find in the `$_SERVER` superglobal variable. You certainly will be able to implement query handling yourself after that: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php